# How to capture dialogflow response?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a dialogflow intent and I want to write a javascript code to get json response of this intent and show it in an html file. I used webhook fulfillment for this intent and now I want to show chat history between dialogflow and user in an html file. I used this javascript code to extract and have dialogflow response:

```
baseUrl = "https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/",
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "query",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "b1973977-20be-4cdc-85a5-7f4225cfdb5a"}),

    success: function(data) {
      console.log("data",data);
      prepareResponse(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      respond(messageInternalError);
    }
  });
}
```

But the json it returns me is incorrect and has no fulfillment part in order to extract correct data and show response.

The returned json is :

```
id: "a0114c2a-afdb-415e-af08-e7a2c5b7d925"
lang: "en"
result: {…}
action: ""
metadata: Object { intentName: "Edit.Attributes", intentId: "9601923d-596b-44df-80de-92dff61869cf", webhookUsed: "true", … }
parameters: Object { VarName: […], percentage: "20%", currncy: "", … }
resolvedQuery: "Change the attribute vacancy rate to 20%"
score: 1
source: "agent"
speech: ""
__proto__: Object { … }
sessionId: "b1973977-20be-4cdc-85a5-7f4225cfdb5a"
status: Object { code: 200, errorType: "success", webhookTimedOut: false }
timestamp: "2018-01-24T12:35:46.342Z"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This is a pretty broad question - narrowing down what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what isn't working would help us help you greatly.

Comment: Please update your question. Trying to read through code in comments is very difficult.

Comment: And explain what you mean by "didn't respond correctly". What did it respond with? What did you expect?

Comment: I have updated the main question now.Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: That doesn't look like a JSON. More like an object dump. In your code, try printing this with something like `console.log('data',JSON.stringify(data,null,1))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention.It has been solved.

Comment: In the spirit of StackOverflow, you should post the solution as an answer to your own question. (As an answer.) This way, if other people run into the same problem, they will have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was the solution:

Putting :

```
url: baseUrl + "query?v=20170712",
```

instead of :

```
url: baseUrl + "query",
```

in ajax call,solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The dialogflow response is contained in speech and displayText propery.